# Redirect stdout to an edit control (Win32)

Tags: winapi, redirect

I have a simple Win32 GUI app which has an edit control in the main window. If I write:

```
printf("Hello world!\n");
```

I would like the text to appear in that control instead of the console. How to?

Update: The app is just simple window with edit control and I can compile it with or without displaying the console (gcc -mwindows). Sometimes I call an external function, which might printf() something - and I would like to catch that something and display it in the edit control. So far, SetStdHandle() seems to be closest to what I try to achieve but I cannot get it to work, yet...

---

Update 2:
Please, can someone tell me why this is not working and how to fix it?

```
HANDLE hRead, hWrite;
CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, NULL, 0);

SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hWrite);

printf("Hello world!\n");

CloseHandle(hWrite); // Why is this needed?

DWORD dwRead;
BOOL bSuccess;
CHAR chBuf[4096];
bSuccess = ReadFile(hRead, chBuf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL); // This reads nothing :(
```

Also, it still prints "Hello world" to the console, I expected it not to..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the API call [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Once the stdout is redirected to your stream, read from it and send the text to the edit control.

[Edit]

Take a look at using [dup2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29.aspx).  The following code seems to work.

```
int fds[2];
_pipe (fds, 1024, O_TEXT);
_dup2 (fds[1], 1);      // 1 is stdout
printf ("Test\r\n");
char buffer[100];
_flushall();            // Need to flush the pipe
int len = _read (fds[0], buffer, 100);
buffer[len] = 0;        // Buffer now contains "Test\r\n"
```

Comment: Ok, this looks like it. But I don't quite follow: when I:
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, my_output) and printf() something it still appears in the console so when I try to read my_output it's empty..?

Comment: would there be a way to pipe the stdout directly to the edit control, so you don't have to do the `_read`? I'm thinking of something like `_dup2(editControlFileDescriptor, 1)`. What I want is to run an app, create a form with a text control, and redirect the app's stdout to the edit control. This way you show I would have to have a thread that periodically does the `read` and dumps it to the edit control.

Comment: I am not familiar with file descriptors associated with windows controls so I suspect not.

Comment: So, how to get this connected to EDIT control? im kinda confused. Looked everywhere but hard to understand.

Comment: You will need to periodically read from the file descriptor, and append any read data to the the edit control.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in Windows by redirecting stdout when you create the process.  You do so by setting flags and setting some handles in the [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28VS.85%29.aspx)  structure passed to [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).  See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for detail on how to set this up.

Once you have that setup can use ReadFile to read from the redirected stdout of the console process then send it to the edit control.

Comment: But I don't start any new processes. It's the same thread. Maybe I don't understand what you meant but the app is already started...

Answer (score -4):

Write a internal __printf function can output the text to edit control, then replace all printf functions with that.