# How to get value of a cell at position (row,column) with openpyxl?

Tags: python, exception, position, cell, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to get a value of a cell at a specific position defined by row and column number.
Code from the documentation doesn't work.

Link to documentation:
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell.

Code from documentation:

> for i in range(1,101):
>   ...        for j in range(1,101):
>   ...            ws.cell(row=i,column=j)

Code gives this Exception:

> warn("Using a coordinate with ws.cell is deprecated. Use ws[coordinate] instead")

Comment: show the line of code in which error occurs?

Comment: @imox
I was trying to create JSON from xlsx table.
https://pastebin.com/WRsWxFyF
`insert_dict[header_row[column]] = test_sheet.cell(row + 1, column + 1).value`

Comment: There may be many error. eg: header_row = get_headers() should be header_row = test_sheet .get_headers()? Can you give me a paste of your whole code?

Answer (score 13):

Use [**`openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.value`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.value) as,

```
wb = load_workbook(file_name, read_only=True)
test_sheet = wb["Test"]
row = 1
column = 1
print(test_sheet.cell(row, column).value)
```

Comment: Including None will trigger an error in openpyxl in the newer versions. Should be omitted.