# How to redirect the STD-Out of an **existing** process in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, stdio

I can easily *start* a process with it's STD I/O redirected but how can I redirect the STD I/O of an existing process.

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(_RunningApplication.AttachProcessId);

process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

string text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //This line blows up.
```

**Exception:**

StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.

---

*Side note: If you know how to do this in C/C++ I'd be happy to re-tag and accept. I just need to know if it's even possible.*

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this without the cooperation of the other process, but if you can arrange such cooperation, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692987/redirect-stdout-to-an-edit-control-win32 may help (since you said C/C++ was okay!).  Problem is that SetStdHandle applies only to the executing process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible in C#.  Looking at possibility in C++.

EDIT:
You can use named pipes in C# and that may be a better way to get IPC if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with you. It doesn't look like its possible. I was already using names pipes for a few of the other IPC streams anyway so I just adopted them for this as well. Many thanks!