# Temporarily capture stdout of a console app in Windows

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to redirect `stdout` (and, optionally, stderr) temporarily to a file, and later recover the original `stdout`?

In a POSIX environment, I use `dup` and `dup2` to store and replace `STDOUT_FILENO`. `freopen` isn't a good solution, since `stdout` cannot be recovered that way.

Is it possible to do this with the Windows API? I believe it is possible using the POSIX-like functions `_DUP` and `_DUP2`. Is there a solution that doesn't involve them?

Comment: If you just want the stdout of a child process, then seems the CRT on windows has a [_popen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(v=vs.110).aspx) that will handle that case simply.

Comment: Hmm, actually this is awesome for a different part of the program, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API. Also, [_dup and _dup2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29.aspx) are available.

**EDIT**

See the following StackOverflow posts.

[Redirect stdout to an edit control (Win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692987/redirect-stdout-to-an-edit-control-win32)

[practical examples use dup or dup2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720535/practical-examples-use-dup-or-dup2)

Comment: The problem with SetStdHandle is that it reroutes the output at a different level than ``freopen()`` and thus won't revert the changes.

Comment: Some additional searching led me to ``_get_osfhandle(_fileno(filestream))`` which will return the HANDLE to a file stream, which you can then use in ``SetStdHandle()``. Seems like a workable solution to me that only uses windows specific functionality ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the reserved file name "CON" means the console output stream. To reattain normal STDOUT behavior on Windows, all you need do is call

```
freopen("CON","w",stdout);
```

Comment: What if this process runs as a subprocess, and its stdout is supposed to be captured? Will CON point to the redirected stdout?

Comment: No. This will always reroute it to the console I/O stream. I'll try Googling a method that retains the original STDOUT.

Comment: Is there a point as to why you want a Windows API specific solution? ``_dup()``, ``_dup2()``, and ``_fileno()`` work just fine

Comment: this answer should be pinned to stackoverflow, I searched for this for ~4 hours tried lots of methods this one is the only one mentioned CON magic! Thanks!!!