# How can I set User Input from Code in C++?

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am creating a test for a function which gets the user input with `std::cin`, and then returns it. The test just needs to check if the input from the user, is the one actually returned.
Problem is, the test should be automated so I can't manually react to the `std::cin` prompt. What can I do to set the input with code?

Comment: Redirect input from a file. `myprogram < input.txt`

Comment: Do you know what OS these tests are going to be run on? If it's a POSIX system, then you can redirect the standard input/output file handles to mock input and output. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385560/c-redirect-or-disable-stdio-temporarily), which is for redirecting stdout but could be easily adapted to redirect stdin instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with automation or redirection of the `std::cin` functionality.
From personal experience it always get much more complicated than it has to be.
A good approach would be to separate your behavior.

Bad:

```cpp
void MyFunction()
{
    std::string a; 
    std::cin >> a;
    auto isValid = a.size() > 1;
}
```

Better:

```cpp
bool ValidateInput(const std::string& myString)
{
    return myString.size() > 1;
}

void MyFunction()
{
   std::string a; 
   std::cin >> a;
   auto isValid = ValidateInput(a); 
}
```

There are more complex solutions to this with `std::cin.rdbuf`.
You could adjust rdbuf - `use this only if you don't have control on the function`.

For example:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void MyFunc()
{

    std::string a;
    std::cin >> a;
    auto isValid = a.size() > 1;

    if (isValid)
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "Hello_World";
    std::cin.rdbuf(s.rdbuf());

    MyFunc();
}
```

Always separate the input functions from the validation functions and the processing functions.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! std::cin.rdbuf is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks, I wrote pseudo code and forgot to fix that :)