# How to capture ossPrint in a Windows application?

Tags: c++, winapi, asn.1

We are using an older version of the ASN.1/C toolkit (v9), and I would like to print selected PDUs to a window in a C++/MFC application.

I know `ossOpenTraceWindow()` exists but as I understand this opens a new window and I want to write to my own GUI.

The documentation for `ossPrintXXX` functions talks about how they are replacements for `printf` / `fprintf` and mention that calling with `world==NULL` will directly call these functions. But I can't see how I can 'connect the dots'.

How can I set things up so that calling ossPrintXXX gives me some characters I can read and display in MFC, since I don't know exactly what is happening under the hood (closed source as far as I known)

*note: in later versions there is a function `ossPrintPDUToBuffer()` but this is not available in v9.*

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1692987/1889329) work for you?

Comment: @IInspectable I am not sure... the OSS docs seem to sometimes say it calls `fprintf` and other times `printf`. I'm hoping for an ASN.1-specific answer as it's (to me) a fairly obscure technology and you can't see the source. Worth a try though.

Comment: Your question seems to be about a product with a commercial license. Please direct your question to the vendor's technical support service.

Comment: @alessandro so we can't ask questions about visual studio, oracle, mssql... There is an asn.1 tag for a reason.

Comment: Also, no we do not have a support license.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a question about a commercial vendor's Tool, your question is better addressed directly to their technical support department.  I notice there is a knowledge base question on the OSS website that might help you in this case.  Please see the following URL: https://www.oss.com/asn1/knowledge-center/asn1-c/asn1c-print-to-memory-buffer-instead-of-window.html